# Hart'ls Ruby Tutorial - Subl Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I use this command? I am up to 1.2.4 Bundler but was unable to run the first part of this section from Hart'l's tutorial. It is simply:

cd first_app/
subl Gemfile

Comment: I know that I have the files before it installed (the git, rails, ruby, gems). I also downloaded Sublime Text and Aptana IDE but am not familiar with either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are two commands.

You have to type it in your console/ terminal.

The first is:

```
cd thePathOfYourApp
```

cd = change directory

and then

```
subl Gemfile
```

means the Gemfile should be open with Sublime (a text editor)

Comment: I'm sorry - what is the console? the command prompt? or Sublime Text (text editor)?

Comment: if you are working on a windows machine it should be the command prompt

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I opened my command prompt (run cmd.exe) and typed in cd first_app. This worked I believe. But when I did subl Gemfile I got the following message: 'subl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file' When I use Sublime text and type that stuff in, how do I compile?

Comment: your command prompt does not know about sublime as text editor. thats why it doesnt know the command subl.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440639/sublime-text-from-command-line-win7
you have to add sublime so that you can use it in command prompt

Comment: but the gemfile has nothing to do with "compilation"

Comment: in order to "start" your app you have to start the rails server with rails s (but I guess this should all be mentioned in hartls tutorial.. ;) )

Comment: OK - THanks so much for your help. Let me look through th eother forum. I downloaded Sublime so let me take a few minutes. But your help is really appreciated!