# Sublime Text 2 not opening using command prompt

Tags: cmd, sublimetext2

Hi I'm a beginner with sublime and laravel. I am trying to launch sublime in command prompt (cmd) and opening the current directory files i am working on and im getting an error that says sublime is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Eg if i run the command c:\wamp\www\laravel\sublime . It should launch sublime and list the current directory files.

I have added the below line into my system variables

```
C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\;%SUBLIME_HOME%
```

and i have also added a new system variable

```
SUBLIME_HOME
```

with value

```
C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sublime Text from Command Line (Win7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440639/sublime-text-from-command-line-win7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `%PATH%` is properly set up to look in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2`, you can run Sublime from the command line using `sublime_text`, which is the name of the executable file, not `sublime`. For example, to open the current directory, just run

```
sublime_text .
```