# Hart'ls Ruby Tutorial - Subl Gemfile not recognized

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm brand new to Ruby and Rails, so sorry if this is a totally ridiculous question. The tutorial book that I'm reading says that I should be able to launch a Gemfile in Sublime Text directly from the command prompt using the subl Gemfile command. When I try this, I get an error that says "subl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file". 
I am in the right directory where the Gemfile is located. 
Ruby is definitely installed and I am using the command prompt with Ruby and Rails.
i have the sublime text 2 and i added the path as i found,but no solution.i even tried :sublime_text Gemfile 
i have tried so many different solutions but no result.
i'm using windows 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

the reason it isn't working isn't a rails question, it is because you haven't set up sublime to work using the command "subl" in your terminal. Try these commands. If you wish to understand the error better, just type in any gibberish into the terminal. It will tell you a similar thing.

```
sudomkdir /usr/local

sudomkdir /usr/local/bin

￼sudo ln-s/Applications/Sublime\Text\2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ￼/usr/local/bin/subl
```

## EDIT

[Sublime Text from Command Line (Win7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440639/sublime-text-from-command-line-win7)

https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/sublime-text-command-line-shortcut-windows

https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/ruby-on-rails-subl-command-not-found

Otherwise, you can refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170)

Comment: He's using Windows, not OS X.

Answer (score 0):

`subl` is Mac only.

For Windows, you need to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 2` to your Environment path,

This will work on Windows 7:

Right click `My Computer`, `Properties`, then `Advanced System Settings`, then `Environment Variables.`. Go down to `System Variables`, and edit `PATH`, you'll need to add the Path to Sublime.

Then you should be able to run `sublime_text my-file` from the command line. (Since the .exe is called `sublime_text.exe`