# Open SublimeText using command promt windows7

Tags: cmd, sublimetext3

Suppose to open a file through notepad using `cmd` we use to write `c:\>notepad text.txt`.

what is the command to open a file through **sublime_text** ?

e.g. `c:\>sublime_text text.txt`

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i guess this is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440639/sublime-text-from-command-line-win7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440639/sublime-text-from-command-line-win7)

Also, please don't use Windows >_< It's a sin. :P