# How to add something to my Powershell profile?

Tags: powershell, sublimetext

Currently I am trying to make it so I can open up files from PowerShell directly in Sublime Text 3.

I am using this command: `Set-Alias subl 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe'`

This works for me initially when I type in "subl filename", but whenever I close out of PowerShell and try it again, it will not work unless I re-type the `Set-Alias` command. Is there any way to permanently make this possible, so I can always type in `subl filename` ?

Comment: Did you make any attempt to Google this?

Comment: Yeah, but I was getting fairly confused from the feedback. Does this link provide the right steps? http://powershellguide.blogspot.com/2008/10/adding-to-your-profile.html

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61374953/1896134

Answer (score 1):

Try running `Get-Help about_Profiles`

As a quick overview:

PowerShell will load the .ps1 file located at the `$Profile` path into the session when it starts. Adding `Set-Alias subl 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe'` to that file will set that alias every time a new PowerShell session is opened.

Comment: I followed those instructions, but when I open powershell now, It gives me the error:

File C:\Users\Me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1 cannotbe loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

Comment: Try running `Get-Help about_Execution_Policies`

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847748.aspx

Im using this website, and am confused which policies to set, and what they should be set to

Comment: Great, i fixed it thank you very much! I just set it to unrestricted, and i am not getting that error, and the powershell profile is loading perfectly

Comment: Vineet: `Unrestricted`, just as `Bypass` are things you shouldn't really set unless you know what you're doing. `RemoteSigned` is a reasonably safe choice.