# Echo newline to powershell console

Tags: windows, powershell

Is it possible to write a newline to the console in powershell?

I tried `echo "\n"` but it is not translated to a new line, it just outputs `\n`.

Comment: If the data is coming from a .php file then `echo "\n";` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`echo` is used in PowerShell all the time. It is an alias for `write-output`.

The issue here is that you need to be using the PowerShell escape character which is a backtick. You can read more about this on [TechNet on about_escape_characters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847755.aspx).

> The following special characters are recognized by Windows PowerShell:
>
> ```
> `0    Null
> `a    Alert
> `b    Backspace
> `f    Form feed
> `n    New line
> `r    Carriage return
> `t    Horizontal tab
> `v    Vertical tab
> ```

So, if you are just trying to break up the output, you can simply use:

```
echo "`n"
```

That will actually output two new lines as all strings sent to `Write-Output` (see `Get-Alias echo`) will be terminated with a new line regardless. Since strings are evaluated as expressions in PowerShell `""` would also work but it would only output the one line.

Also, since this data is being sent to the standard output stream, it will be captured by variables and pipelines. `Write-Host` might be a better option if that is something you want to mitigate.

Comment: So it needs " double quotes and not single quotes.

Comment: Double quotes permit expansion where as single quoted strings are interpreted verbatim . You can see more in [Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.4)

Answer (score 11):

Just do `""` It will print a blank line

Comment: _echo is rarely used in PS_. `Get-Alias echo` would beg to differ

Comment: Brilliant and cross-platform

Answer (score 9):

You should it use like this:

```
PS D:\> "This is an `n example!"
This is an
 example!
```

[image: PS]

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Test `nNewLine"
```

or

```
echo "Test " "NewLine"
```