# How to add project path to PYTHONPATH in sublime text 3

Tags: python-3.x, build, project, sublimetext, pythonpath

[Check project tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJCkF.png)
Hello. I'm trying to run example.py , but have problems with importing src. It can't find module.
I can solve this problem, writing:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

now sys.path have path to folder of the project
D:\...\cubic_reg-master, and may check all packages and modules in project.
But I don't want to write it in every folder/every script. Trying to find how to config Build System or project.sublime-settings.

p.s. Have worked in Pycharm, and trying Sublime Text, as I understand Pycharm add path automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

who seeks will always find

Decision is to run python with arg -c; make there settings and run file

Here is mine Build System file:

```
{
   "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.python",
   "shell": "true",
   "windows":
   {
           "cmd": ["D:\\Development\\Python\\Anaconda3\\python", "-c", "import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '$project_path'); exec(open('$file_name', 'r').read());"]
   }
```

}

p.s. probably it's dangerous solution, I will be glad to look at better ways

p.p.s. for plugin sublime Repl same settings work, but should use $folder and $file_basename:

```
BrowsePackages -> SublimeREPL\config\Python\Main.sublime-menu
{...
    "cmd": ["D:\\Development\\Python\\Anaconda3\\python", "-i", "-c", "import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '$folder'); exec(open('$file_basename', 'r').read());"],
```

...
    }

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
six months later

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Found better decisions:

1) build system have option 'env'
first idea is to write "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "$project_path"},
but it don't know such variable $project_path for env opt, so this works

```
{
   "working_dir": "$project_path",
   "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "."},
    "cmd": ["D:\\Development\\Python\\Anaconda3\\python", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

disadvantages: incorrect working_dir - if you create or read files - should consider it

2) better way is to use some commands in cmd:

```
{
   "windows":
   {
      "shell": "true",
      "cmd":"set PYTHONPATH=$project_path & D:\\Development\\Python\\Anaconda3\\python -u $file",
   },
   "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.python",
}
```

3) add PYTHONPATH to mine_proj.sublime-project with plugin 
"environment settings"

use there real path or %project_path% (.sublime project stores in project, to use %project_path% turn on "set_sublime_variables")

EnvironmentSettings - User

```
{
    "set_sublime_variables": true
}
```

mine_proj.sublime-project:
add only "settings" part

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "name": "Anaconda Python Builder",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "shell_cmd": "\"python\" -u \"$file\""
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "env":
        {
          "Windows":
          {
                "PYTHONPATH": "%project_path%"
          },
        }
    },
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should rarely ever have to change your PYTHONPATH. It's a bit hard to understand your question, but I am assuming you want to add sublime text to your regular PATH so you can call a project in sublime text from command line. To do that see this article...

For OSX: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html

For Windows: [Sublime Text from Command Line (Win7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440639/sublime-text-from-command-line-win7) see first answer

Comment: doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: No, I'm trying to make comfortable IDE with sublime text. So, I created sublime project, made custom system build with anaconda 3. (http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html). Now I want sublime text to add project directory to sys.path. Then package examples will be able to find package src. tried 
    // "env":
    //     {
    //         "PYTHONPATH": "$project_path",
    //     },